# jquery ui dialog with bootstrap centered without position fixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

im using jquery UI dialog to make dialog with form. Also im using bootstrap to format and jquery ui bootstrap to combine them (https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap)

For dialog initialization im using this code. Im trying to make dialog appear in center of screen, but it without fixed position. So when user scroll, dialog will move away. Is it posible?

```
function addProjectDialog(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    unselectTableItem();
    closeAllDialogs();

    var form = $("#newProjectFormContainer");

    form.dialog({  
        title: "New project",
        autoOpen: false,
        position: {
            my: 'center', 
            at: "center"
        },

        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        beforeClose: function(){ 
            $.noty.closeAll()    
        }

    });


    form.dialog('open')
    form.find('.text').val("")
    form.find('.date').val(getTodayDate())           
    form.find('.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }); 
    form.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected')
    form.find('textarea').val('')         
}
```